# Unexpected padding in inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

Run the snippet below, and you will see that these two balck boxes occupy more space than they need (vertically). Why is that so? I have tried settting margin / padding to 0, but it did not work.

```css
div.ex4 {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: visible;
}

.imag {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex4"><div class="imag"></div><div class="imag"></div></div>
```

Comment: no they are occupying 20 px each both width and height

Comment: . can't you use `display: flex`?

Answer (score 0):

use `font-size: 0;`

```css
div.ex4 {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: visible;
font-size: 0;
}

.imag {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex4"><div class="imag"></div><div class="imag"></div></div>
```

Comment: I don't seem to figure out how it all related to `font-size`! could you help with this?

Comment: i don't konw too,.... but u can google

Comment: @Sapinder don't use font-size:0 it's a hack. Check the duplicate for the correct solution